# What do I need to do to connect an ADC IC to a Adam 6066??Is it even possible to read the inputs from the ADC chip?

Tags: adc, communication, plc, datalogger

I am working on a input array that uses a ADC ([MCP3208](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwihkMSGkcLbAhUrqlkKHX4YCSMQFgg_MAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mouser.com%2Fds%2F2%2F268%2F21298c-68472.pdf&usg=AOvVaw25GXNizFBBHIMJh-cvbxi_) or something similar) to read in several analog inputs and convert them to Digital signals that go into an [ADAM 6066 Module](http://downloadt.advantech.com/ProductFile/PIS/ADAM-6066/Product%20-%20Datasheet/ADAM-6066_DS20140613100712.pdf). What would I need to do to communicate the inputs from the Analog to the ADC to the Adam and read the data into a program? I want this to report to a data logger and use the relays to trigger events from the inputs. I know usually read each channel as one thing, or as my experience so far. I kinda new to all this so I am sorry if I am not being clear.

Edit:Added link to datasheet

Comment: At least have the courtesy to link datasheets for those products you mention. Why wouldn't you just buy an ADAM module with an ADC?

Comment: I am trying to limit the number of units I need to implore to one which is the [link](http://www.advantech.com/products/todatasheet/e256cafc-36dd-4740-86a0-d7e53b5c4ddf?utm_source=corpsite) 'adam 6066' which only has digital inputs and 6 relays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursory look at the data sheets (The ADAM datasheet leaves a little bit to be desired):  ADAM is max input frequency of 3KHz, ADC (MCP3208) is min output frequency of 10KHz.  Seems you will need a bridge to get the values from the ADC to the ADAM (reliably).  Maybe use a small CPLD to do this.

e.g.  ADC -> SPI Read of the ADC slave (GTE 10kHz) into a FIFO -> ADAM read/sample of ADC values from FIFO (LTE 3kHz)...  repeat.

Not sure of the ADAM... those are 6 digital inputs.. so, maybe you have to send/apply the data to the ADAM and it samples it/them(?)  Bottom line, it does not appear that the ADAM is capable of reading the ADC directly.

Comment: I am only sending the data to the Adam and having it foreword the input through TCP Modbus. I only said the MCP3208 because I had a few on hand from another project but I would match the frequency to the Adam for simplicity.

Comment: Take a look at this Analog Devices site for choosing ADCs:  http://www.analog.com/en/products/analog-to-digital-converters.html  Most have serial interfaces for "digital out", but a few that are >1 ksps have parallel interfaces, albeit more than 6 bits, but maybe you don't need that much resolution(?).  I think you will likely end up needing a bridge, but maybe one of the listed devices will suffice your requirement(s).

Comment: In reality I am using the PLC to pass the ADC signal to the interface system I would have setup.

Comment: The idea for this came from a post in the [Arduino forum](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21536/expanding-analog-inputs-to-the-arduino) about using the (MCP3208) to get additional analog inputs to your board and I was wanting to know if this was possible with a plc like the Adam 6066.

Comment: Well, I don't know ADAM from Adam, but it seems to me that you are going to need to process the ADC data in a CPLD/FPGA/microprocessor (i.e. make decisions) and then, using those outputs, affect the ADAM inputs accordingly to control your relays.